# sql group by personalised condition

Tags: sql, group-by

Hi，I have a column as below

```
+--------+--------+
| day    |  amount| 
+--------+---------
| 2      |   2    |
| 1      |   3    | 
| 1      |   4    | 
| 2      |   2    |
| 3      |   3    | 
| 4      |   3    |
+--------+--------+
```

now I want something like this sum day 1- day2 as row one , sum day1-3 as row 2, and so on.

```
+--------+--------+
| day    |  amount| 
+--------+---------
| 1-2    |   11   |
| 1-3    |   14   | 
| 1-4    |   17   |
+--------+--------+
```

Could you offer any one help ,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
with data as(
select 2 day, 2 amount from dual union all
select 1 day, 3 amount from dual union all
select 1 day, 4 amount from dual union all
select 2 day, 2 amount from dual union all
select 3 day, 3 amount from dual union all
select 4 day, 3 amount from dual)
select distinct day, sum(amount) over (order by day range unbounded preceding) cume_amount
from data
order by 1;

       DAY CUME_AMOUNT
---------- -----------
         1           7
         2          11
         3          14
         4          17
```

if you are using oracle you can do something like the above

Comment: thanks @ShoeLace, I think your answer is fantastic , but I'm not using oracle, i'll find if my database has similar function, thanks a lot

Comment: @riversxiao do you want to update your question with your database type then.. it'll help others provide better answers

Comment: I'm using database maxcompute provided by aliyun , not a main stream database, so i'm afraid not many people used it before.

Comment: even more important to mention it then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the day range in left column always starts from "1-", What you need is a query doing cumulative sum on the grouped table(dayWiseSum below). Since it needs to be accessed twice I'd put it into a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dayWiseSum AS 
(SELECT day,SUM(amount) AS amount FROM table1 GROUP BY day ORDER BY day);

SELECT CONCAT("1-",t1.day) as day, SUM(t2.amount) AS amount 
FROM dayWiseSum t1 INNER JOIN dayWiseSum
t2 ON t1.day > t2.day 
--change to >= if you want to include "1-1"
GROUP BY t1.day, t1.amount ORDER BY t1.day

DROP TABLE dayWiseSum;
```

Here's a fiddle to test with: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1656/1/0

Note: Since sqlfiddle isn't allowing `CREATE` statements, I've replaced `dayWiseSum` with it's query there. Also, I've used "Text to DDL" option to paste the exact text of the table from your question to generate the create table query :)